# Is there a term for a subgraph which includes all the edges of a graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology, computer-science

A subgraph is called spanning when it includes all of the vertices of the given graph.

Is there a term for a subgraph which includes all the edges of a graph?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If the subgraph includes all edges of the original graph, then it also includes all its vertices, except *maybe* some with degree $0$.

The *minimal* such subgraph is the graph in which all $0$-degree vertices were removed. It is called the **$1$-core** of the graph, a very special case of [$k$-core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)).

Comment: Why do you have to remove all the vertices of degree 0? If you only remove some of the vertices of degree 0 then it still contains all the edges.

Comment: Indeed! I thought we were talking of the _minimal_ such subgraph, but this is not in the question. The original graph itself actually is one such subgraph. I edited the answer to make this clear, thanks.